# how to search for something in a file and what to do when it inst found

Tags: python, file, search, text-files

```
with open("stock.txt","r") as file, open("receipt.txt","a") as r:  
    for line in file:  
        found = False    
        if code in line:  
            found = True  
    if found:  
        ...
    if not found:
        ...
```

I'm trying to find `code` in `file`, however when I run this it only seems to search the last line of the file.

Comment: well, what are you trying to do?

Comment: You reset `found` to `False` for every line. Also, you could use `else` instead of `if not found:`.

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with your logic

As suggested by @leaf the explanation of your logic along with mine

You were setting `found = False` when reading every line but checking the value of found only after you have read the file.
The modification done is that it now checks the value of found for every line.

Please try the following:

```
with open("stock.txt","r") as file, open("receipt.txt","a") as r:  
for line in file:  
    found = False    
    if code in line:  
        found = True  
    if found:  
        ...
    else:
        ...
```

Comment: _"There is something wrong with your logic..."_ - Well what? Saying there is _something_ wrong isn't really helpful to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have the `if found:` and the `if not found:` lined up with the `for line in file`. When it should actually be indented by one tab.

Try this instead:

```
with open("stock.txt","r") as file, open("receipt.txt","a") as r:  
    for line in file:  
        found = False    
        if code in line:  
            found = True  
        if found:  
            ...
        else:
            ...
```